# django: select_related() on an already-existing object?

Tags: python, sql, database, django, performance

If I am retrieving an object with django, I can use `.select_related()` to instruct django to get all foreign key objects as well, to wit:

```
obj = ModelClass.objects.select_related().get(id=4) #1 db hit
foo = obj.long.chain.of.stuff #no db hit
```

If I already have `obj`, without it having been `.select_related()`, that is:

```
def doit(obj):
    obj.long.chain.of.stuff #4 db hits
```

is there any way to get django to fill in all of its foreign key relations? Something like:

```
def doit(obj):
    obj.magic() #1 db hit
    obj.long.chain.of.stuff #no db hits
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose I can do:

```
def doit(obj):
    obj = obj.__class__.objects.select_related().get(id=obj.id) #1 db hit
    obj.long.chain.of.stuff #no db hits
```

But is there any nicer way?

Comment: I think that's going to be your only way. I'd make sure to comment that bit of code though, so anyone looking at it later won't be scratching their head wondering why that was done, or worse, remove it because it looks redundant.